# Autoredirect to predefined option with javascript in dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have a drop-down list with a predefined value in it. So, when user clicks on select-box, it should automatically redirect to that default value defined in function. A simple example (still not working :( ) is below; but on each select that predefined value is selected. Also, it must work, when user clicks back on "Select" option. I hope I was clear enough, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PreselectMyItem(itemToSelect)
    {
        // Get a reference to the drop-down
        var myDropdownList = document.frmPreselect.lstNames;

        for (iLoop = 0; iLoop< myDropdownList.options.length; iLoop++)
        {    
            if (myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value == itemToSelect)
            {
                myDropdownList.options[iLoop].selected = true;
                break;                  
            }                     
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="frmPreselect" name="frmPreselect">
    <select onclick="PreselectMyItem(6)" id="lstNames" name="lstNames">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">America</option>
        <option value="2">Africa</option>
        <option value="3">Russia</option>
        <option value="4">Australia</option>
        <option value="5">Sergey</option>
        <option value="6">UK</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify the description. What exactly should happen a) when the user opens the dropdown, b) when he makes a selection there, c) when he opens it again? Exactly how should things differ from the effect of simply using the attribute “selected”? Currently, the code sets a particular option selected so that the user cannot change the selection by clicking (hitting return works), because the onclick event handler interferes—so a more complicated approach is needed. But I’m afraid it might get complex, especially if you take into account keyboard navigation issues, too.

Comment: Thaks Jukka for reply , basically this should work like a hind , in a select box will be hundreds of countries , but i want to make for user that they do not need to scrool in all list to find UK , it will be automaticcaly be preselected by this function ...

Comment: Would it not be much simpler to just make UK the selected one by default? I know that wouldn't select it automatically when the user clicks it a 2nd time, but I think that behavior would really annoy users anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your server-sided code is able to put the "6" into , so it should just as well be able to create

```
<select id="lstNames" name="lstNames">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">America</option>
    <option value="2">Africa</option>
    <option value="3">Russia</option>
    <option value="4">Australia</option>
    <option value="5">Sergey</option>
    <option value="6" selected="true">UK</option>
</select>
```

Into it. Maybe I just didn't understand your question, but this should be the cleanest way.

Comment: yes , i know that , but i need not this way as on select item another javascript function is triggered depending on what value is ....